# Double start of activities when skipping login

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

We've been using Firebase for a user to login. According to our manifest, the main launcher is our Login activity. When it starts, it checks whether the user is connected or not. If it is, it launches another activity, otherwise it stays on the login page.

The problem: When we start the app and we are connected, we can see some sort of double activity opening animation since the login page opens and half a second later the main activity starts.

How to fix this?

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ultramirinc.champs_mood">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ScheduleAdder"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_schedule_adder"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/> 
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".TabActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tab"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".NotificationObject"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".FriendProfilActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
</application>
```

login:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    //getting firebase auth object

    //if the objects getcurrentuser method is not null
    //means user is already logged in
    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        Log.d("Login debug", "current user: " + firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().toString());
        //close this activity
        UserManager.getInstance().getUserInformations();
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TabActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);



    //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    //toolbar.setTitle("Champlain mood");
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    // Set up the login form.
    mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    populateAutoComplete();

    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (id == R.id.login_text || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                attemptLogin();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
    mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            attemptLogin();
        }
    });

    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    //mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
}
```

Comment: I think, this is the usual behavior because you are actually starting your LoginActivity then OtherActivity. Instead you can actually start your OtherActivity and check the login then take the decision to stay here or put the LoginActivity in.

Comment: I think you should use splash activity where you can check whether you are logged in or not.

Comment: Great idea! I never heard of it! Thanks a lot!!